# How can I split multiple polygons using a polyline or any other feature in arcgis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

[image]

I am trying to split this polygons of the districts by using the polyline that passes through the district into multiple polygons and get the area of each of these polygons. I have tried the analysis toolbar split option but, it did'nt work plus there is only option for selection of one polygon only

Answer (score 1):

Feature to polygon would do the trick if you have an advanced licence.

Otherwise, I am afraid that you will need to make two polygons manually on each side of the river, then you can use the split tool. If you only have one long river, this is quite fast to do with the "tracing" tool [image]

Comment: There is a tool in advanced editor to split polygons that are edited. Select polyline, unselect any polygons and click it.